# Why does Crystal Reports hang my web page?

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports-2010

I am pretty new to ASP.Net and have developed a simple web application using CrystalReportsViewer. I have a "Home" page where the desired report is selected, and a "ViewReports" page to render the report. For debugging, I have hard-coded the path to the *.rpt file.

When debugging using the ASP.Net Development Server, I can load the report just fine and it loads fairly quickly. However, when the application is hosted in IIS (on the same machine), the "ViewReports" page never loads - it gets to about halfway then just hangs. No errors at all. If I remove the RPT file, the page loads with the expected "Error loading report" message. Any ideas? I am using .NET 4.0 with VS 2010 and Crystal Reports for VS 2010. Also, I can include code if that would help, just let me know what portion you would like to see (I didn't want to flood the question with unnecessary code if it wouldn't be helpful).

UPDATE (5/31 2:59pm)

I do indeed see a plethora of errors in the event log (good call, Christopher). The message is as follows:

```
The description for Event ID 4353 from source Crystal Reports cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event: 

The keycode assembly, BusinessObjects.Licensing.KeycodeDecoder.dll, cannot be loaded.


the message resource is present but the message is not found in the string/message table
```

Should this missing assembly be included in the CR runtime?

Comment: Code could help but I would also check the event viewer on the IIS box for a detailed error message.

Comment: Does the server have the necessary print drivers? Sounds strange but I've seen it happen, it gets hung on a "Install print driver?" phantom dialog...see http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-21490 and http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-21418